# track changes for tables in SQL Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want a to keep track of all the operation (Insert, Delete and Update) in a database.

I know the track changes and masking property in SQL but that value is not sufficient for my requirement.
here

1. In case of  insertion  and Deletion i need Primary key of Inserted/Deleted record
2. in case of updation i need updated column name, its value and primary key.
   because using this i will update the values in 3rd party tool.

Comment: You are looking for a trigger

Comment: Not exactly.Is there is any system table that keep track of updation along with coloumn name or any other possibilty???

Comment: So it sounds like you want to implement your own type of replication. I suggest you try searching on that term first. Otherwise, you can find many discussions about logging changes by searching with your title.

Comment: Not Replication but i want to keep Log of updation in Database in a seperate table

Comment: it is possible to do this with trigger or temporal tables.

Comment: ok. can u pls help me to find sysytem table that keep record of updates.